# How to include commas in Oracle external table

Tags: sql, oracle, external-tables

I have a pipe delimited file that contains commas on the very last field like so:

```
COLOR|CAT|CODES
Red|Pass|tiger, 12@fol, letmein
Blue|Pass|jkd@332, forpw, wonton
Gray|Pass|rochester, tommy, 23$ai,
```

I terminate the last column by whitespace, and everything works out good with no errors, except that it will only include/read the first value and first comma in the last column e.g. tiger, jkd@332, etc. Obviously because of the whitespace after the comma.

How do I include the commas without getting any errors? I have tried `" "`, `/r`, `/n`, `/r/n` and even excluding the `"terminated by"` in the last column, and while those will work to include the commas, I will get the `ORA-29913` and `ORA-30653` reject error every time I select all from the external table (contains thousands of records).

I have the reject limit to `10`, but I don't want to change it to `UNLIMITED` because I don't want to ignore those errors, also I cannot change the file.

My code:

```
    --etc..
    FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|'
            OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
            MISSING FIELD VALUES ARE NULL
    --etc..
    CODES CHAR TERMINATED BY WHITESPACE
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how:

```
SQL> create table color (
  2    color      varchar2(5),
  3    cat        varchar2(5),
  4    codes      varchar2(50)
  5  )
  6  organization external (
  7    type oracle_loader
  8    default directory ext_dir
  9    access parameters (
 10      records delimited by newline
 11      skip 1
 12      fields terminated by '|'
 13      missing field values are null
 14      (
 15        color    char(5),
 16        cat      char(5),
 17        codes    char(50)
 18      )
 19    )
 20    location ('color.txt')
 21  )
 22  parallel 5
 23  reject limit unlimited;
SQL>
SQL> select * From color;

COLOR CAT   CODES
----- ----- --------------------------------------------------
Red   Pass  tiger, 12@fol, letmein
Blue  Pass  jkd@332, forpw, wonton
Gray  Pass  rochester, tommy, 23$ai,
SQL>
```

Comment: Hey thanks Littlefoot. Unfortunately, it's still not getting everything... so I actually had to check thousands of records only to find out that some of the last field has a comma at the end, e.g.: rochester, tommy, 23$ai,  <--- comma at the end, thus it ignores this. I'll go ahead and edit my post. Any other way around this?

Comment: I spoke too soon, adding the "whitespace" did get everything, but then I'm back to square one where it only reads the first comma'd value

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand what you are saying. I added the 3rd example into my .TXT file and selected from unchanged external table, and got *everything*. See edited output I posted a moment ago. Is that not what you want?

Comment: Yes that's exactly what I wanted, but I have a little over 50k records, and I'm missing  about less than a hundred. Not sure what's wrong, I'll go ahead and check again when I get home. I'll keep you updated!

Comment: Ok, so I checked and some of the codes have more than the specified size, doh! Fixed the size and now it works, thanks!